# git pull --rebase not yeilding deseired outcome

Tags: git

I lost the changes I did to my files after doing a git pull --rebase. I have absolutely no clue all that happened here , but in the end , I ended up checking out my changes ( backing them up in a seperate folder ) pasting back before commiting. Here is the entire terminal showdown.

```
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Gemfile.lock
        modified:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
        modified:   app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
        modified:   lib/card/print_manager.rb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git add -u
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git status
On branch card_application
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/card_application'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   Gemfile.lock
        modified:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
        modified:   app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
        modified:   lib/card/print_manager.rb

thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git commit -m "Cleaning up temp pdf folder, reading directly from s3"
[card_application 04e9712] Cleaning up temp pdf folder, reading directly from s3
 4 files changed, 53 insertions(+), 57 deletions(-)
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'https://github.com': userid@gmail.com
Password for 'https://**********:
To https://github.com/gitrepo/application.git
 ! [rejected]        card_application -> card_application (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gitrepo/application.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git pull --rebase
remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
From https://github.com/user2/application
   458a7f6..c1021f4  card_application -> origin/card_application
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Cleaning up temp pdf folder, reading directly from s3
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       app/controllers/application_controller.rb
<stdin>:227: trailing whitespace.
      #file =
<stdin>:246: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:303: trailing whitespace.

warning: 3 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        Gemfile.lock
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Cleaning up temp pdf folder, reading directly from s3
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /mnt/c/Sites/application/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git checkout Gemfile.lock
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git rebase --continue
app/controllers/application_controller.rb: needs update
app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb: needs update
lib/card/print_manager.rb: needs update
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git diff app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
fatal: ambiguous argument 'app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git status
rebase in progress; onto c1021f4
You are currently rebasing branch 'card_application' on 'c1021f4'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
        deleted:    app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
        deleted:    lib/card/print_manager.rb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git rebase --continue
app/controllers/application_controller.rb: needs update
app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb: needs update
lib/card/print_manager.rb: needs update
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git add app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.

thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git log
commit c1021f41cc7e01b3ee3c766698a3acbbd05824b3
Author: User1 <user1@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 17 00:40:00 2016 -0400

    Pre-filling instruction started

commit 458a7f6b353803453208da89c98e8f0e5f4dcf6e
Author: User2 <user2t@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 16 22:48:55 2016 -0400

    fixes continued

commit e92138bef7b6ad575cff7690621ab017cca4183f
Author: User3 <user3@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 16 17:59:42 2016 -0400

    Added tooltips to eligibility modal and attorney signup page.  Added to Attorney Landing Page

commit 8d20bd7d29cdd42814e1872c4a70d453b14f8134
Author: User5 <user5@somedomain.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 16 22:27:52 2016 +0530

    Checked nil before destroying any record in card application

commit 688dd02069c9c7e35ea5bbc4f80f7860e95e9987
Author: User5 <user5@somedomain.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 16 22:05:03 2016 +0530

    Removed required validation for other names in applicant general tab. Also fixed the issue with applicant intending

thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git cherry -v
Could not find a tracked remote branch, please specify <upstream> manually.
usage: git cherry [-v] [<upstream> [<head> [<limit>]]]

    --abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display SHA-1s
    -v, --verbose         be verbose

thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git cherry -v origin/card_application
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git rebase --abort
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git cherry -v origin/card_application
+ 04e971223b5907305fbe95867a8db58e0de0ea4a Cleaning up temp pdf folder, reading directly from s3
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 04e971223b5907305fbe95867a8db58e0de0ea4a
Gemfile.lock
app/controllers/application_controller.rb
app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
lib/card/print_manager.rb
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git checkout 04e971223b5907305fbe95867a8db58e0de0ea4a Gemfile.lock
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git checkout 04e971223b5907305fbe95867a8db58e0de0ea4a app/controllers/application_controller.rb
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git checkout 04e971223b5907305fbe95867a8db58e0de0ea4a app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git checkout 04e971223b5907305fbe95867a8db58e0de0ea4a lib/card/print_manager.rb
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git reset HEAD~
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       Gemfile.lock
M       app/controllers/application_controller.rb
M       app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
M       lib/card/print_manager.rb
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git pull
Updating 458a7f6..c1021f4
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git stash "mychanges"
usage: git stash list [<options>]
   or: git stash show [<stash>]
   or: git stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: git stash [save [--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                       [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]]
   or: git stash clear
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on card_application: 458a7f6 fixes continued
HEAD is now at 458a7f6 fixes continued
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git pull
Updating 458a7f6..c1021f4
Fast-forward
 app/controllers/application_controller.rb                                       |  5 +++--
 app/views/card_application/completion.en.html.haml                                   | 21 ++++++++++++++-------
 .../card_application/prefiling_instructions_concurrent/_passport_photos.en.html.haml |  8 +++++---
 app/views/card_application/prefiling_instructions_concurrent/_us_status.en.haml      |  6 ++++--
 4 files changed, 26 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git unstash.pop
git: 'unstash.pop' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git unstash
git: 'unstash' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git stash apply
Auto-merging app/controllers/application_controller.rb
On branch card_application
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/card_application'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Gemfile.lock
        modified:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
        modified:   app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
        modified:   lib/card/print_manager.rb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git add -u
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git status
On branch card_application
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/card_application'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   Gemfile.lock
        modified:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
        modified:   app/uploaders/pdf_uploader.rb
        modified:   lib/card/print_manager.rb

thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git commit -m "Cleaning up temp pdf folder , reading directly from s3"
[card_application 0379504] Cleaning up temp pdf folder , reading directly from s3
 4 files changed, 53 insertions(+), 57 deletions(-)
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'https://github.com': rachit.pant@gmail.com
Password for 'https://afasdfasdf':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/gitrepo/application.git/'
thisuser@DESKTOP-ENS2652:/mnt/c/Sites/application$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'https://github.com': userid@gmail.com
Password for 'https://userid@gmail.com@github.com':
Counting objects: 51, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1.53 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (9/9), completed with 9 local objects.
To https://github.com/gitrepo/application.git
   c1021f4..0379504  card_application -> card_application
```

Comment: To add to the question , this is linux bash within windows. I never faced this issue before, ever since I started using linux within windows( WSL) , this has happened more than once.

Comment: Don't know about `git pull --rebase`. I would have done `git fetch origin/[branch]` and `git rebase FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: I can probably help here, but the steps you took are too vague to know what really happened.

Comment: The push was rejected. so I did a git pull --rebase. There were some conflicts during the rebase, after resolving the conflicts when I did rebase --continue, it said " needs update" to all the files that were in my commit and deleted two of my files. I was not sure why this message appeared so checkedout those files using my commit key. But nothing helped. I had to take backup of my files and do a reset to solve this! Also the funny thing here is git status at the very beginning showed my branch is up-to-date with the remote. Not sure what happened exactly!

Comment: One thing that is an issue here (not necessarily *the* problem, but certainly causing some annoyance) is that you are using a rather old version of Git, pre-2.0. It's less important since Git version 1.8.* but I find it better to do `git fetch` followed by a separate `git rebase` (if needed and desired), instead of `git pull --rebase`. Since your Git may predate 1.8.* you may want to avoid `git pull` (though, even post-2.0, `git pull` is still a "convenience" that is more inconvenient than convenient, in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to get what's wrong from your 300 or so lines of bash (from which probably 90% are useless). But I guess you're doing something wrong during the rebase.

For each step (each commit you are rebasing), if there is a conflict (and it seems you have), you need to edit the conflicted file(s) with an editor or mergetool (kdiff, meld, winmerge, ...). Once the conflict is resolved (no more `<<<...`, `===...` or `>>>...` in your files), you add the files (`git add ...`) and continue your rebase (`git rebase --continue`) withtou commiting.

Before you start a rebase, make sure your working directory is clean (by stashing, commiting or canceling your local changes).

It doesn't hurt [to have a look at the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) if you're not sure how rebase work cause it's not trivial if you're new to git.

Comment: Exactly a conflict should so that. But in the case here, its marking the file as deleted. Please see the bash log, its 300 lines but a lot of it can be skipped. This most likely looks like a bug in wsl implementation.